# I'm running Prefect for the first time and have an error running my first python code in the tutorial

Tags: orchestration, prefect

I installed Prefect in a virtual environment and created a small python function in my vscode. I tried running the code but got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\Prefect\prefect_basics.py", line 1, in <module>
from prefect import flow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prefect'
```

I am confused because I downloaded Prefect 2.0 in my virtualenv

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading to the latest version with `pip install prefect -U`. I suspect you might be using venv? We've seen some issues with that virtual environment setup. Using Conda virtual environment should work. If it doesn't, you can build a Minimal Reproducible Example and open a GitHub issue here https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues